# How can i remove this blank page after my list of figures?

Tags: errors, formatting, input, include, setspace

All chapters of my work have enough text in them to fill atleast two pages, so this is not an issue, but for my list of figures, i get this empty page after wards:
[image: Page 1]
[image: page2]

This is my main page:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,bibtotoc,idxtotoc,headsepline,footsepline,footexclude,BCOR12mm,DIV13]{scrbook} 

% include settings
\input{components/settings}

% include commands
\input{components/commands}


%\makeindex
    %% inter line spacing
%\linespread{1.0}

\makeglossary

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter
 %... other text here, no settings
    \mainmatter

        \listoffigures
    %\bibliography and stuff

\end{document}
```

My Settings:

```
% Included by MAIN.TEX

\renewcommand{\sectfont}{\normalfont \bfseries}        % Schriftart der Kopfzeile

% manipulate footer
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ifoot[\footertext]{\footertext} % \footertext set in INFO.TEX
%\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\rmfamily}

%% allow sophisticated control structures
\usepackage{ifthen}

% use Palatino as default font
\usepackage{palatino}

% enable special PostScript fonts
\usepackage{pifont}

% make thumbnails
\usepackage{thumbpdf}

%to use the subfigures
%\usepackage{subfigure}


\usepackage{colortbl}


%% show program code\ldots
%\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage{program}

\usepackage{multirow}

%% use colors
\usepackage{color}

%% make fancy math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{yhmath} % f�r die adots 
%% mark text as preliminary
%\usepackage[draft,german,scrtime]{prelim2e}

%% create an index
\usepackage{makeidx}

% for the program environment
\usepackage{float}

%% load german babel package for german abstract
%\usepackage[german,american]{babel}
\usepackage[german,english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{english}

% use german characters as well
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}       % allow Latin1 characters

% use initals dropped caps - doesn't work with PDF
\usepackage{dropping}


\usepackage{styles/shortoverview}
\ifx\pdftexversion\undefined
 %% use PostScript graphics
 \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.epsi}
 \graphicspath{{figures/}{figures/review}} 
 %% allow rotations
 \usepackage{rotating}

 \usepackage[hypertex,hyperindex=false,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\else %% reduce output size \pdfcompresslevel=9

 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.JPG,.png,.pdf,.eps}
 \graphicspath{{figures/}} 

 %% Load float package, for enabling floating extensions
 \usepackage{float}

 %% allow rotations
 \usepackage{rotating}
 %% use pdftex version of hyperref
 \usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red,citecolor=red,%
 anchorcolor=red,urlcolor=red,bookmarks=true,%
 bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=0,plainpages=false%
 bookmarksnumbered=true,hyperindex=false,pdfstartview=%
 ]{hyperref}
\fi
```

Comment: Is the list of figures the last item in your actual document, or does something else come afterwards?

Comment: Well, someone already posted, that i should do open=any and that seems to work ...
But no, it is not the last thing, the bibliography still follows

Comment: Actually, it was me that posted, but then I saw that your list of figures appeared to be at the end of the document, which I thought rendered my answer incorrect. I will update and reinstate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Book chapters usually start on an odd numbered (recto) page. In your case, page 22 is left blank so that whatever comes next can start on page 23. You can use the option `open=any` to turn off this behaviour.

```
\documentclass[open=any]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{This is a chapter}
abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is obviously not the place to ask, but do you know, whay \makeglossary does not list \listoffigures?@Ian Thompson

Comment: @CleboSevic --- I don't understand the question. `\makeglossary` creates a glossary, and `\listoffigures` creates a list of figures.

Comment: Yes, but the list of figures is not listed in the glossary ... eventhough it should, should it not?

Comment: @CleboSevic --- Are you by any chance mixing up 'glossary' and 'table of contents'?